# Define own loss and classify error in cntk

Tags: classification, customization, cntk, loss

I understand people typically use the loss and error below to train

```
ce = cross_entropy_with_softmax(z, label_var) 
pe = classification_error(z, label_var) 
trainer = Trainer(z, (ce, pe), ...)
```

Can we override or define own loss and error methods?  What we really need is to add weights when we calculate loss and error. For instance, we have 4 classes, it is important(more weight) to not misclassify the first class as other class and vice versa, but not as important(less weight) if it misclassifies among the last 3 classes.  What is the best way to handle that in cntk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any CNTK expression is a valid loss or error: Here cross entropy:

ce = C.negate(C.reduce_sum(C.element_times(target, C.log(prediction)), axis=-1))

Comment: That's great!  I am struggling to figure out how I can add the weights to the example you provided.  I am thinking to create NxN array of error_weights, where N is number of classes. However, I am not sure how to create a valid loss using error_weights, ResNet Model, z, and input label_var, which is similar to cross_entropy_with_softmax(z, label_var).  Would be possible to give me some simple example code or some directions that I can follow?  Thanks!

Comment: I guess I can create method below if I can get output from model z.  Is there anyway to get prediction from model?                                                      def my_criterion(z, target):
    prediction = get_from_model(z)   
    loss = calculate_loss_with_weights(prediction, target)
    return loss